# ODBC Driver Manager Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303) - Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, mysql, odbc, windows-server

I have a problem with adding MySQL server via linked server to my SQL Server Database

Following [this instruction](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/) unfortunately just does not work out for me.

I added four data sources, 2 using 64-bit mySQL ODBC drivers and 2 using 32-bit drivers:

[image]

Test connection brings me success

[image: from each one source.]

Linked server configuration:

[image: Configuration screen 1]

[image: Configuration screen 2]

But I am still getting

[image: this error.]

Software used:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit
- MySql Connector/ODBC 8.0 32bit/64bit
- Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
- Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio 2018

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any news here? Did you resolve this issue?